SQL Formatting a string (name)
I can't quite figure this out.
I have a name_matrix table that unfortunately comes to me in one column as shown below.
Some of the names come in with a space after the comma, some of them without it. Some of the names come formatted correctly, while some are all lowercase, or all uppercase.



rowid
name




1
Smith,John


2
Smith, John


4
smith,john


5
SMITH, JOHN



I'm trying to figure out how to remove the space, if there is one... separate the last name and the firstname... capitalize the first letter of each and lowercase the rest of the name.
So far I have this query, that formats the name correctly IF there is no space. This query correct rows 1 and 4 -
SELECT Upper((LEFT(split_part(name, ',',2),1))) ||
         lower(substring(split_part(name, ',',2), 2, 99)) AS firstname, 
       Upper((LEFT(split_part(name, ',',1),1))) ||
         lower(substring(split_part(name, ',',1), 2, 99)) AS lastname
FROM name_matrix`

If there is a space, the result looks like this; (I added an underscore to show a space).



firstname
lastname




_john
Smith



I tried to use a REPLACE in front of the UPPER, but that only removed the space and didn't capitalize the firstname first char.

Assuming you can have two names in the first or last, right? Such as "Mary Ann" for first, or "Smith Jr." for last?

I didn't even think about this. This throws a huge wrench into my gear.

For your sampe data, SELECT INITCAP(SPLIT_PART(REPLACE(name,' ',''), ',',2)) AS firstname, INITCAP(SPLIT_PART(REPLACE(name,' ',''), ',',1)) AS lastname FROM name_matrix; would do, see this sample fiddle. But hard to tell if this cover all possible cases. Could you please tell us what strings/names are possible? I guess the real situation is much more difficult than this small sample data?

Add those names too to your sample data: Malcolm McDowell, Conan O'Brien and Carl van der Walt

Trying to do this is really challenging. In addition to the above examples. a lot of the non-western people I work with have  3 (or more) names, first letters aren't always upper case, etc.

You can use a combination of initcap (for capitalizing first letter even if multiple first letters such as Mary Lee Smith), ltrim (for removing the leading space) and split_part. Assuming you have names such as MARY LEE SMITH, you want to be careful or avoid using TRIM or REPLACE when dealing with your spaces.
select 
 rowid, 
 name, 
 initcap(split_part(name, ',', 1)) as last_name, 
 initcap(ltrim(split_part(name, ',', 2))) as first_name --ltrim removes space by default
from 
 name_matrix




rowid
name
last_name
first_name




1
Smith,John
Smith
John


2
Smith, John
Smith
John


4
smith,john
Smith
John


5
SMITH, JOHN
Smith
John



fiddle

This solved ALL of my problems! I thank you so much!!!
